# Как лучше связывать бины?

Tags: spring, bean

Для связывания бинов есть три способа:

1. @Autowired
2. сеттеры
3. конструкторы

Знаю, что в предыдущей версии спринга рекомендовали связывать бины через поле и аннотация, сейчас же рекомендуют через конструктор, а поле наоборот не использовать.

Прошерстив документацию спринга так и не понял зачем и почему?